# Is there a way to get the key id and fingerprint of an AsymmetricKeyParameter in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, bouncycastle, openpgp

I'm creating an OpenPGP key with the following example code using BouncyCastle:

```
IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator kpg = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
kpg.Init(new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.ValueOf(0x1), new SecureRandom(), 2048, 33));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = kpg.GenerateKeyPair();
```

Is there a way to get the KeyId and Fingerprint of the public part of the `AssymetricCipherKeyPair`, i.e `kp.Public`?

I know that if I can somehow get an instance of `PgpPublicKey` that information is there ready to be consumed, but I'm not sure if that's possible?